# MethodDecorator.Fody and getting parameter values

Tags: fody

I was wondering if with MethodDecorator it's possible to have the passed parameter during the OnException... that would be great since if I can catch an exception I can also have the passed parameter values

Consider this piece of code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Worker worker = new Worker();

        worker.DoWork(6);
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Module)]
public class LoggableAttribute : Attribute, IMethodDecorator
{
    public void OnEntry(System.Reflection.MethodBase method)
    {
        var args = method.GetParameters();


        var arguments = method.GetGenericArguments();

    }

    public void OnExit(System.Reflection.MethodBase method)
    {

    }

    public void OnException(System.Reflection.MethodBase method, Exception exception)
    {

    }
}
```

and

```
public class Worker
{
    [Loggable]
    public void DoWork(int i )
    {

    }
}
```

I wish to have 6 on the OnEntry/Nor OnException

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone stumbles upon this like I did, you can add an Init method and capture the argument values there. 
e.g:

```
public class LoggableAttribute : Attribute, IMethodDecorator
{
    private object[] arguments;

    public void Init(object instance, MethodBase method, object[] args) {
        this.arguments = args;
    }

    public void OnEntry()
    {
        // this.arguments[0] would be 6 when calling worker.DoWork(6);
    }
}
```

Check out the example on https://github.com/Fody/MethodDecorator